Active Singleton with Passive Hot Failovers in Kubernetes
I need a singleton that receives API request and produces Kafka messages, but I'd also like one or two hot, passive standbys that kubernetes will fail over to if the active fails. The passives would not have connectivity until the switch over. It doesn't matter if there is sometimes more than one pod for a second or two. Ideally I'd like to do this out of application, but if I have to implement something like raft so be it. I was thinking a stateful set but not sure how to do it. Any ideas?

Seems possible by having the container adjust the pod's labels: https://faun.pub/active-passive-load-balancing-with-kubernetes-services-742cae1938af

Why does it need to be a singleton; can you just run multiple replicas and let a Kubernetes Service round-robin between them?  How would you define and observe "failure"?  What language and framework are you using for your application?
